# Security of Solidity versus Rust

Tags: solidity, security, rust

I recently started learning `Solidity`, and I am interested in security aspects. Today, I encountered a very interesting blog article discussing security vulnerability in `Rust`. At my level of understanding, other vulnerabilities being commented on here except for the `first` and the `third` one may not be the case for `Solidity`, which gave me an impression that `Solidity` has a stronger security character than `Rust`. I wish that I can hear from other experts if my idea is not wrong. Please openly discuss the items below in the article, and please also suggest if there are more security considerations, in general, writing a contract in `Solidity`. Thanks.

**1. Missing Ownership Check**

Smart contracts commonly contain privileged functionality that should only be accessible to
certain accounts. If this is the case, then a smart contract should verify that an account is
trusted before running this privileged functionality.

All Solana accounts are owned by smart contracts–to this rule there is no exception.
Only contracts are allowed to modify accounts’ data. It is the smart contract developers’
task to implement necessary authorization controls, including the verification of
the transaction sender’s digital signature.

Account metadata struct in Solana includes the owner field that indicates the public key
associated with that account’s owner. To validate that an account is trusted, the public
key stored in its owner field should be checked against expected values.

Some Solana smart contracts use config or other utility accounts to store trusted data
or the public key of an administrator’s account.  Those accounts have to be provided
by users running the smart contract and executing certain actions.

However, if a contract does not validate the owner of a utility account, it could be
vulnerable to exploitation. An attacker could bypass access controls with a fake config
account if the account’s owner isn’t verified to be as expected and trick the smart
contract to perform privileged operations.

Instead of inherently trusting certain accounts, Solana smart contracts should verify
that they are owned by the contract’s owner.

**2. Lack of Signature Validation**

For restricted functionality, checking that the public key of the calling account matches
that of an authorized user is an important first step. However, an account can technically
set its data to whatever it wants; it’s just data.

Verification occurs when the account signs an operation with the private key associated
with that public key.  If a smart contract fails to check that an operation is signed,
then anyone can call that instruction as long as their account contains the correct public key.

Solana smart contracts should validate that an operation is signed with an appropriate
private key before executing privileged functionality.

**3. Integer Overflows and Underflows**

Rust (and other programming languages) store values in fixed-size variables.  This means
that these variables can only hold a certain range of values.  If an operation results in
a value outside of this range, it creates an integer overflow or underflow.

In the debug mode, Rust will check for overflows and underflows, but this is not true in
the release mode (which is used by the Solana BPF toolchain).  If a value moves outside
the range of values that a variable can support, it will wrap around.

An attacker can exploit this fact to evade validation of transfers of value.  If a program
checks that a + b < c and a and b are not added together in the transfer, then an attacker
could choose the values of a and b to overflow the check.  Later, when the transfer occurs,
only one value is used, which means that it will not overflow and a large amount of value
will be sent to the indicated address.

Integer overflows and underflows typically result from unsafe math and unsafe casts between
variable types.  If it uses checked versions of the arithmetic and cast operations, a smart
contract will throw an error if an overflow/underflow occurs, causing the transaction to be
canceled.

**4. Failure to Validate External Programs**

Smart contracts are designed to interact with one another and call functions from external
programs. Solana’s design patterns state that programs to be invoked within a function should
be passed to that function as an argument.

Function arguments may be under the user’s control, which means that an attacker could supply
malicious inputs. By passing a lookalike program as an argument to a vulnerable function,
an attacker could convince the smart contract to run that program (and sometimes even assume
the calling program’s identity) instead of the one that they intended.

Like verifying accounts based on their public keys, smart contracts should verify the programs
that they invoke based on their public keys. This verifies that the program is the one that
the smart contract intended to invoke.

**5. Missing Account Structure Validation**

A Solana smart contract may define multiple different accounts for different purposes.
These attacks can have different structures and contain different types of data.

Account data is passed to a Solana smart contract function as a byte array, which the recipient
then deserializes based on the structure of the expected account type. This creates an opportunity
for exploitation where a malicious user creates an account of one type and passes it to a smart
contract function as an instance of another type of account.

A check of the ownership of the account would pass ownership checks if it was created by one of
the contract’s own functions. However, the data associated with that account would be interpreted
based on the perceived account type, which could allow the attacker to set certain values and pass checks.

This attack takes advantage of the fact that one type of account could be substituted for another.
If an account’s data starts with an identifier unique to that type of account and that value is
checked by the functions using that account, then this attack is not possible.

*Reference*

```
[1] Rob Behnke, 04.11.2022, https://halborn.com/how-to-hack-solana-smart-contracts-programs/
```

P.S. I believe this post is very relevant for us to openly discuss even though it does not contain even a single line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this question is that Rust is very rarely used among this community of Ethereum developers. I do not know much about Rust, but what I do know is that Ethereum smart contracts get attacked a lot more often than contracts on Solana. Solidity is very secure if you know what you are doing, and you read the documentation of the packages and imported contracts that you are using. Most imported smart contracts that add functionality to another smart contract such as one that would allow you to create a multi-sig wallet needs to be reviewed. I do not know if you have read up on this "attack" but you should if you have not.[HackerNoon MutiSig Wallet Frozen](https://hackernoon.com/parity-wallet-hack-2-electric-boogaloo-e493f2365303)

If you know exactly what you are doing, you will be fine using Solidity. After reading what you post posted, it seems as if Rust allows for a lot more haphazard error. Not many people know Rust compared to Ethereum, and networks such as Solana which mainly use Rust do not have as many users as the Ethereum network which makes it less of a target. Solidity > Rust = Technical Security. Rust > Solidity = Less likely to be attacked.

Comment: Your comment is more in the social engineering aspect that there are more Ethereum chain users (and locked value) than Solana. If we go back to the technical scope where we're interested in the security feature of Solidity, do what the reference article says with item numbers 2, 4, and 5 NOT happen with Solidity by the construction of the language itself? Or, should a Solidity developer also take care of item numbers 2, 4, and 5 in the article?

Comment: So with 5 I know for a fact that Solidity developers do not have to worry much about this. In regards to #2, the link that I listed above was a problem that occurred because of a lack of signature validation because the _owner needed to be set twice in that instance. An outside user was able to call a function that allowed them to set themselves as the owner of that contract. This has since been patched, but I would be careful. I could not tell you much about #4, but I would say it is safe to assume that you do not have to worry about that.

Comment: In your link above "HackerNoon...", it says "The first Parity Wallet Hack contained a bug that allowed anyone to execute initWallet". Such a contract does not make any sense. Unfortunately, I see that there aren't many developers interested in this post at the moment. Therefore, I mark your opinion as an answer.